# Friend Referal Script

Tags: php, api, contacts, friend

I want to know how to write a script that connect to different mail servers and load the list of friends, something like that is found on facebook and other sites.

Mainly, I want to connect to hotmail, gmail and yahoo.

Comment: And what is your question? You can't expect someone to give you full code on how to connect to different mail boxes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Tatu Ulmanen: I have searched but couldn`t find anything, everything is kinda blacklisted!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is contact API's.

http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/google_releases_contacts_api.php

http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463989.aspx

You can find more, you just have to search the terms  `something contact api` and you should get a whole slue of information. If you want to find a script for PHP add php to those terms.